# How to get percentage of total for each row in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with hundreds of columns. A simple example is this df:

```
date       | A | B | C 
2020-01-01 | 10| 40| 50
2020-02-01 | 20| 60| 100
```

But I want %of total row-wise:

```
date       | A   | B    | C 
2020-01-01 | 0.1 | 0.4  | 0.5
2020-02-01 | 0.11| 0.33 | 0.55
```

How do I do that in pandas?

Comment: Get the sums rowwise and divide values by it. Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you want to divide all column except `date` column

```py
cols = df.filter(regex='^(?!date$)').columns
df[cols] = df[cols].div(df[cols].sum(axis=1), axis=0).round(2)
# or
val = df.filter(regex='^(?!date$)')
df.update(val.div(val.sum(axis=1), axis=0).round(2))
```

```
print(df)

         date     A     B     C
0  2020-01-01  0.10  0.40  0.50
1  2020-02-01  0.11  0.33  0.56
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough:

```
(df[['A', 'B', 'C']].T / df[['A', 'B', 'C']].sum(axis = 1)).T
```